# symfony - 500 error page customisation problem

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4

I am ready to push a site to production (currently on staging), but I'm having a slight problem with the internal server error 500 page.

I have created a file in `web/errors/error500.php` and I've also got: `ErrorDocument 500 errors/error500.php` in my .htaccess file

The problem is, if there is a 500 error in the admin, it displays the symfony default 500 page instead of mine in the `errors` folder.

Does anyone have a rough idea why this is?

I've cleared symfony cache, cleared browser cache and used several browsers.

Thanks

Comment: If it's any help, [this](http://symfony-check.org/permalink/customize-the-oops-an-error-occurred-page) is the advice I followed to get mine working, but it doesn't use .htaccess...

Comment: Yeah i looked at that and realised that the error needed to be in the config folder :)

Comment: Cool; in that case I'll post a proper answer that you can accept :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The standard Symfony way of doing this isn't with an Apache ErrorDocument directive, but simply by putting your error page in either `<project>/apps/<appname>/config/error/error.html.php` or `<project>/config/error/error.html.php`, for per-app or general error pages respectively. See [this checklist item](http://symfony-check.org/permalink/customize-the-oops-an-error-occurred-page) on the very handy [Symfony Deployment Cheat Sheet](http://symfony-check.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure you are not in debug mode when you test this otherwise it will still show full stack trace.